# getting child view content in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm working on expandable for practice. I used to get my own adapter to show the child list. But I won't be able to get the value of the child view. Please help me on this. The code goes like this.

AddPerson.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddPerson extends Activity{
    ExpListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_person);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explistAdap);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                      listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("FREQUENTLY_CONTACT_WITH");
        listDataHeader.add("GROUPS");
        listDataHeader.add("CONTACT_BOOK");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> FREQUENTLY_GOZZYPED_WITH = new ArrayList<String>();
        FREQUENTLY_GOZZYPED_WITH.add("JOHN ");
        FREQUENTLY_GOZZYPED_WITH.add("RISHIKA");
        FREQUENTLY_GOZZYPED_WITH.add("AMIT");


        List<String> GROUPS = new ArrayList<String>();
        GROUPS.add("OFFICE GROUP");
        GROUPS.add("CLUB GROUP");
        GROUPS.add("FAMILY");
        GROUPS.add("CHAT");


        List<String> CONTACT_BOOK = new ArrayList<String>();
        CONTACT_BOOK.add("AMIT");
        CONTACT_BOOK.add("MAA");
        CONTACT_BOOK.add("PAA");
        CONTACT_BOOK.add("AAKRITI");
        CONTACT_BOOK.add("PUJA");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),FREQUENTLY_GOZZYPED_WITH ); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), GROUPS);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), CONTACT_BOOK);
        }
    }
```

ExpListAdapter.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{


    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code for `ExpListAdapter` class

Comment: @GauravGupta: I have added the adapter. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

try this inside onChildClick :

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
String value = tv.getText().toString();
```